# Conditionally make a page read-only using react

Tags: html, reactjs, jsp

I want to create a React webpage that has both editable and read-only versions, the whole page not just a few elements on the page. A version is displayed to the user based on user id and other conditions. How do I do it?

The only straight forward way I know is to create 2 pages one editable and one read-only and based on the condition show the appropriate version (html page) to the user.

Is there a better and smarter way to do this? Like can I create just one page for both versions and toggle the mode based on the condition to the users?

Answer (score 1):

Your question should have provided an example of some code you had tried but based on the description, very rough example below of one of many possible solutions.

Suppose `EditView` component is your page and you are able to pass a value for `permission` based on whatever credential you need to apply.

Then you have a component, `ExampleField` that takes the `permission` and displays either an input or static text. A collection of multiple of these fields is mapped from a theoretical array of data that you'll have to fetch from somewhere and the `fields` are returned by the main component.

```
const EditView = ({permission}) => {
  const [editable, setEditable] = useState();
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setEditable(permission);
  }, [permission]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //maybe fetch your data from a back end or whatever and assign it to `values`
    //on page load
  }, [])
  
  const ExampleField = ({permission, val, index}) => {
     const handleChange = (e) => {
       let vals = [...values];
       vals[index] = val;
       setValues(vals);
     }
     return(
       <>
         {permission
          ? <input name="example" type="text" defaultValue={val}
              onChange={handleChange} />
          : <span>{val}</span>}
       </>
     )
  }
  
  const fields = values.map((value, i) => {
    return <ExampleField permission={permission} val={value} index={i}/>
  })
  
  return(
          <>
           {fields}
          </>
  )
}
```

Most likely, you'll want to break out various field components into their own file and, instead of using `useState`, you would probably want to explore `useContext` or `useStore` type functionality to lift up your state and do all the react things.

*Haven't tested or even compiled this code - for illustration purposes only.